# Smallest number of vertices in tree with specific degrees.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees, extremal-graph-theory

> Find, with proof, the smallest number $r$ of vertices in a tree having two vertices of degree $3$, one vertex of degree $4$, and two vertices of degree $6$. Give an example of such a tree.

Clearly, I need to make use of the degree requirements to impose a lower bound on the number of vertices. Intuitively, I think the higher the average degree, the more vertices there'll be as compared with graphs with lower degree. I know a few properties about trees, including the fact that every tree with at least two vertices has at least $2$ leaves. Trees are connected graphs without cycles. So far, the smallest number I can find is $19,$ and that is by placing the vertex of degree $6$ at the root and by making the other vertices as neighbours. But this approach seems too simple; it's likely that the minimum number is smaller. Clearly it's greater than $7$.

Comment: @RobPratt using the handshaking lemma, I get something like $r = 12 + \dfrac{n_1}2 + n_2 + \dfrac{5}2 n_5$, but I can't seem to get a good lower bound for this. Perhaps considering cases when $n_5 = 0, 1, 2, $ etc. might help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $d \ge 1$, let $n_d$ be the number of vertices of degree $d$.  Then we have
\begin{align}
r &=\sum_d n_d \\
2(r-1)&=\sum_d d n_d 
\end{align}
By eliminating $r$, we find that
$$2\sum_d n_d = 2 + \sum_d d n_d,$$
equivalently,
$$0 = 2 + \sum_d (d-2) n_d.$$
We are given $n_3 = 2$, $n_4 = 1$, and $n_6 = 2$, so
\begin{align}
0 &= 2 - 1n_1 + 0n_2 + 1n_3 + 2n_4 + 3n_5 + 4n_6 + \sum_{d \ge 7} (d-2) n_d \\
&= 2 -n_1 + 0 + 2 + 2 + 3n_5 + 8 + \sum_{d \ge 7} (d-2) n_d \\
&= 14 -n_1 + 3n_5 + \sum_{d \ge 7} (d-2) n_d.
\end{align}
Hence $$n_1 = 14 + 3n_5 + \sum_{d \ge 7} (d-2) n_d \ge 14,$$
and so $$r \ge n_1 + n_3 + n_4 + n_6 \ge 14 + 2 + 1 + 2 = 19.$$